# mysql schedule collision data

Tags: mysql, collision, schedule

I have schedule data course like below, how i can detect there was any data collision / clashing data on it? in mysql syntax

```
+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+
| IDCourse  | Day    | Class  | Room    | IDTeacher | Capacity | Residue | Begin  | End   |
+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+
| MI09BB11  | Monday | A      | A.1.4   | RA        | 40       | 1       | 08:00  | 10:00 |
| MI09BB12  | Monday | A      | A.1.4   | RA        | 40       | 1       | 08:30  | 10:30 | <-- clash 
| MI09BB51  | Monday | A      | A.1.4   | RA        | 40       | 1       | 11:00  | 13:00 |
-
-
-
+-----------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Sorry my bad english. thanks

Comment: What constitutes `clashing data`?  Do you mean if any rows begin and end times overlap?

Comment: data above is real current data on database.
i want to make sure that data is entered by user (php front-end) can be detected, that entered data is valid and there is no collision data with previous inserted data.
how do i solve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s1.IDCourse, s2.IDCourse, s1.Day
FROM schedule s1
JOIN schedule s2
ON s1.Day = s2.Day AND s1.Room = s2.Room AND s1.IDCourse != s2.IDCourse
WHERE s1.Begin BETWEEN s2.Begin AND s2.End
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you're looking for rows whose time ranges overlap with other entries?

If so, you can compare your times like this:

```
SELECT T2.IDCourse, T2.Begin, T2.End
FROM YourTable T
    INNER JOIN YourTable T2 ON
            T.Day = T2.Day AND
            T.Begin <= T2.End AND 
            T.End >= T2.Begin
```

---

EDIT: As @Barmar has appropriately pointed out, this will produce results that will conflict with themselves.  Do you have a primary key on this table?  Add it (or your unique identifier) to your `JOIN` or `WHERE` criteria:

```
WHERE T.PrimaryKey <> T2.PrimaryKey
```

Comment: You're checking for one time range being entirely within another. But the conflict in the example isn't like that.

Comment: You're also going to treat every course as conflicting with itself.

Comment: @Barmar -- Good call on the course conflicting with itself -- I edited the answer accordingly.  However, this concept should work with overlapping date ranges, not just those in their entirety.

Comment: You're right, I misread your query. I thought you were checking `T.Begin >= T2.Begin AND T.End <= T2.End`