# I cant able to execute my mysql query while testing inlocalhost phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT s1.roomtype, s2.roomno, s1.checkin,s1.checkout
FROM guestrocordtransac s1
JOIN guestrocord s2
ON s1.roomtype = s2.roomtype AND s1.roomno != s2.roomno
WHERE s1.checkin="2015-06-06 00:00:00"
BETWEEN s2.checkin="2015-06-06 00:00:00" AND s2.check0ut="2015-06-13 00:00:00"
```

This is how tried to execute the query and below is the error i am getting

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'== s2.roomno WHERE s1.checkin="2015-06-06 00:00:00" BETWEEN   
s2.checkin="2015-  06' at line 4
```

Can any one help me out of this?

Comment: why can't you execute it? what errors do you get?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== s2.roomno WHERE s1.checkin="2015-06-06 00:00:00" BETWEEN s2.checkin="2015-06' at line 4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT s1.roomtype, s2.roomno, s1.checkin,s1.checkout
FROM guestrocordtransac s1
JOIN guestrocord s2
ON s1.roomtype = s2.roomtype AND s1.roomno != s2.roomno
WHERE s1.checkin="2015-06-06 00:00:00" AND
s2.checkin BETWEEN "2015-06-06 00:00:00" AND "2015-06-13 00:00:00"
```

Specifically the problem seems to lay with your `where` clause. You need to add in the `and` after your first clause, and before the `between` clause. Also, you have the syntax of the `between` clause slightly wrong. it should be `<value> between <check value1> and <check value 2>`

The query above should be a fixed version.

Comment: no its not working out...Again its shows like this ......... #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN s2.checkin="2015-06-06 00:00:00" AND s2.check0ut="2015-06-13 00:00:00" ' at line 6

Comment: Yes. because that is incorrect syntax, and isn't the syntax in this answer - can you explain in words what you're trying to accomplish? Because it's unclear from your query

Comment: Interesting, a syntactically correct and explained answer, which can't get any better without some additional info in the question, gets downvoted.. for what?

Comment: i got it pala_ kind of you for having time in this.I made a mistake in it from what you have given

Comment: SELECT s1.roomtype, s1.roomno, s1.checkin,s1.checkout FROM guestrocordtransac s1 JOIN guestrocord s2 ON s1.roomtype = s2.roomtype AND s1.roomno != s2.roomno WHERE s1.checkin BETWEEN s2.checkin AND s2.checkout .................how to code this query with my form values.... .....can i able to give where s1.checkin='$date1' between s2.checkin='$date1' and s2.checkout='$date2'....having trouble with single and ddouble quotes...

Comment: you'll need to ask a separate question for that - as it's not the same thing as this one

Answer (score -1):

Your between syntax is wrong ,correct it and it should work.
Next time please post the error also.
Your where and between usage is wrong.See syntax on net and rectify your query.
If not able to do it let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646503/mysql-schedule-collision-data.    I was trying to do exactly the same with values in my code

Comment: SELECT s1.roomtype, s1.roomno, s1.checkin,s1.checkout FROM
guestrocordtransac s1
JOIN guestrocord s2
ON s1.roomtype = s2.roomtype  AND s1.roomno != s2.roomno 
WHERE s1.checkin BETWEEN s2.checkin AND s2.checkout  .................how to code this query with my form values....

Comment: can i able to give where s1.checkin='$date1' between s2.checkin='$date1' and s2.checkout='$date2'

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to do.post the whole thing